# How does dist function work in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB code which I try to convert to C, and it works all fine, but I'm stuck at [`dist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/dist.html) function. It says that it calculates the Euclidean distance weight function. Calculating the normal Euclidean distance function is pretty easy, but I don't exactly get what the weight means here. In the code that I want to convert there is 1x1000, or to say in another words just a row array with complex values (meaning x + yi). Then it does something like this:

```
if ((dist(sest(i), -1)) < (dist(sest(i), 1)))
```

As I said `sest` is the 1x1000 matrix of complex values, so it takes each value in a `for` loop and puts it into the `dist` function with -1 or 1, and the output of `dist` function in my case is again a complex number. Any idea what's going on behind the scene? What -1 and 1 is doing there? How is the Euclidean weight function calculated here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the

```
((dist(sest(i), -1))
```

is just the equivalent of

```
abs(sest(i) + 1)
```

and

for real numbers.
    ((dist(sest(i), 1))

is the equivalent of

```
abs(1-sest(i))
```

for real numbers.

for complex numbers it seems to be that

```
((dist(sest(i), -1))
```

is the equivalent of

```
conj(abs(real(sest(i)) + 1)+ imag(sest(i))*j)
```

and

```
((dist(sest(i), 1))
```

is the equivalent of

```
abs(1 -real(sest(i))) + imag(sest(i)*j)
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the last part `((dist(sest(i), 1))`, the output should again have `conj` in my opinion.